# Python requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.10.10.10', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, request

I'm writing a script to check a large list of URLs and return the HTTP status codes for each one. I tried everything I could think of, or find online for the exception handling. The script runs for a while, then it crashes eventually with the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.10.10.10', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /wmedia (Caused by NewConnectionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1029bfe10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address",))
```

I think the server gets overwhelmed with too many requests after a while, and the sleep time doesn't help.

This is the worker function I'm using with process pool:

```
def get(url):
r = requests.get(url, timeout=2)

try:
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
    pass
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("OOPS!! Connection Error")
    r.status_code = "Connection refused"
    time.sleep(2)
    print(str(e))
except requests.Timeout as e:
    print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
    r.status_code = "Timed out"
    time.sleep(2)
    print(str(e))
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("OOPS!! General Error")
    r.status_code = "Error"
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Someone closed the program")
    r.status_code = "Interrupted"
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    r.status_code = "Error"

return param, r.status_code
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `urllib` to get HTTP status code. [This site](http://tomheath.com/blog/2008/04/list-of-http-status-codes-comma-separated/) has all the possible HTTP status code separated by commas (that I used in example below  as '*httpStatusCodes.txt*').

```
import urllib
from collections import defaultdict

adict = {}
with open("httpStatusCodes.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        (key,val) = line.split(',')
        adict[int(key)] = val
```

So we read all the status code in a dict and make provision for when code is not available.

```
adict = defaultdict(lambda: "'Code not defined'", adict)
```

Then we iterate through a list of site and get its status codes.

```
websites = ['facebook.com', 'twitter.com', 'google.com',   
            'youtube.com', 'icantfindthiswebsite.com']
for url in websites:
    try:
        code = urllib.urlopen('http://' +url).getcode()
    except IOError:
        code = None
    print "url = {}, code = {}, status = {}".format(url, code, adict[code])
```

Notice that I purposely listed `icantfindthiswebsite.com` to simulate sites that cant be reached. This exception is handled via `IOError:`.

**Result**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
url = facebook.com, code = 200, status =  OK
url = twitter.com, code = 200, status =  OK
url = google.com, code = 200, status =  OK
url = youtube.com, code = 200, status =  OK
url = icantfindthiswebsite.com, code = None, status = 'Code not defined'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great suggestion, but I think my issue is primarily caused by the web server getting overwhelmed. I'm checking a large list of directories against the same server to see if they exist or not.  I want to add some way of slowing down when the server stops responding, instead of crashing the script.  Also I'm surprised that the last general exception block does not save it from dying.

Comment: Is it possible to post websites and directories you are trying to get? Another idea will be to use `.getcode()` first. Once you receive a response code, then proceed with further checking. That way it will slow down as well as catch any HTTP errors.

Comment: I have a local virtual machine running a site with Apache and using a wordlist, something like this one: https://github.com/digination/dirbuster-ng/blob/master/wordlists/common.txt